# How do I migrate changes in Django when I'm uninheriting a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I have two models and one inherits from another and setup the database with migrate etc. like so:

```
class TemplateProduct(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(TemplateProduct):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

Then how would I migrate the db to make it so that Product does not inherit from TemplateProduct? Say I just want these models instead:

```
class TemplateProduct(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

When I try to migrate this, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "templateproduct_ptr_id" of relation "product_product" does not exist
```

And then when I remove the delete "templateproduct_ptr_id" from the migration, I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field u'id' in class 'Product' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'TemplateProduct'
```

As the title says: how do I migrate changes in Django when I'm uninheriting a model?

Comment: did you run ```python manage.py makemigrations``` - if so - what did that produce?

Comment: I ran it and it said that it is to delete the template_product_id_ptr and add an id.

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was to delete both models. Then `python manage.py makemigrations --merge`, then I added the models back the way I wanted them, finally running `python manage.py makemigrations --merge` again to add the models back in.

This may not be the most elegant solution but it worked.